# on reducing a that-clause to a non-finite clause

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality

I saw a basic sentence but i was confused while trying to type its reduction. I have a question born from the sentence below.

- *It was not surprising that he was elected President.*

How can I reduce this sentence using a non-finite clause?

1. *It was not surprising for him to be elected president.*
2. *He was not surprising to be elected president.*

Is either of these grammatically correct ? If not, what is a correct alternative?

Comment: "[For him to be elected president] was not surprising", where the infinitival clause is subject.

Comment: Your example "It was not surprising for him to be elected president" is fine. It's the extraposed equivalent of my example.

Comment: is the second one grammatically correct ?

Comment: No, it's ungrammatical. It requires the adjective "surprised": _He was not surprised to be elected president_.